# angularjs not resolving $locationProvider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm working with angularjs, and after trying ngRoute and watching a couple of courses on pluralsight about angular routing I'm trying to make a small project using ui.router

```
(function(){
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',['ui.router']);

myApp.config(['$stateProvider','$locationProvider',function($stateProvider,$locationProvider){

    $locationProvider.html5mode(true);

    $stateProvider.state('home',{
        url:'/',
        templateUrl:'views/home.html',
        controller:'homeController',
        controllerAs:'home',
        resolve:{
            controller:['$q',function(){
                var defer = $q.defer();

                require([],function(){
                    defer.resolve();
                });

                return defer.promise;

            }]
        }
    }).state('login',{ 
        url:'/login', 
        templateUrl:'views/login.html',
        controller:'loginController',
        controllerAs:'login',
        resolve:{
            controller:['$q',function($q){
                var defer = $q.defer();

                resolve(['resources/js/sha512.js','controllers/login.js'],function(){
                    defer.resolve();
                });

                return defer.promise;
            }]
        }
    }).state('parent.index',{ url:'' });


}]);

myApp.factory('sessionService',function(){
    var session = {
        status: false,
        get status(){ return status; },
        set status(nStatus){ status = nStatus;},
        privilege:0,
        get privilege(){ return privilege; },
        set privilege(nPrivilege){ privilege = nPrivilege; }
    }

    return session;
});
```

}());

And my browser is getting a funky error, "Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/$injector/modulerr?p0=superiorTech&p1=%24locationProvider.html5mode%20is%20not%20a%20function%0A%40http%3A%2F"

which I can infer it means the dependency injector couldn't resolve $locationProvider, after reading angular's documentation I verified that $locationProvider is part of angular's core module so it should not be an issue, there's no other code yet, all other files are blank.

Comment: can you pl post your code and share link either via plunker or jsfiddle?

Comment: @YuvaRaj A jsfiddle would not work because of the webapp's layout, there are several files

Comment: you can recreate multiple files setup in http://plnkr.co/ of in codepen